# How to publish docker images to docker hub from gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci, docker-registry

Gitlab provides a `.gitlab-ci.yml` template for building and publishing images to its own registry (click "new file" in one of your project, select `.gitlab-ci.yml` and `docker`). The file looks like this and it works out of the box :)

```yaml
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Official docker image.
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY

build-master:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
  only:
    - master

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  except:
    - master
```

But by default, this will publish to gitlab's registry. How can we publish to [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) instead?

Comment: **Never** specify ":latest" as your image in a CI script. Your build is not reproducible anymore

Answer (score 82, accepted):

No need to change that `.gitlab-ci.yml` at all, we only need to add/replace the environment variables in project's pipeline settings.

### 1. Find the desired registry url

Using `hub.docker.com` won't work, you'll get the following error:

> Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://hub.docker.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found

Default docker hub registry url can be found like this:

```bash
docker info | grep Registry
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

**index.docker.io** is what I was looking for.

### 2. Set the environment variables in gitlab settings

I wanted to publish [gableroux/unity3d images](https://hub.docker.com/r/gableroux/unity3d/) using gitlab-ci, here's what I used in [Gitlab's project > Settings > CI/CD > Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html)

```bash
CI_REGISTRY_USER=gableroux
CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=********
CI_REGISTRY=docker.io
CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE=index.docker.io/gableroux/unity3d
```

`CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` is important to set.
It defaults to `registry.gitlab.com/<username>/<project>`
regsitry url needs to be updated so use `index.docker.io/<username>/<project>`

Since docker hub is the default registry when using `docker`, you can also use `<username>/<project>` instead. I personally prefer when it's verbose so I kept the full registry url.

This answer should also cover other registries, just update environment variables accordingly.

Comment: Could be great to explain where we can do these action more precisely than just " add/replace the environment variables in project's pipeline settings."

Comment: @ArnaudF. I just updated the answer with your suggestion. There are many ways to set the environment variables in a gitlab-ci pipeline. You can do it in the project's CI/CD settings page, but it can also be done using the `variables` key in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`. It is preferable to keep secrets in the settings to prevent to keep them hidden.

Comment: I am getting "The push refers to repository [docker.io/user/repo]" still by changing index in registry image

Comment: Please note that https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html warns: "Avoid overriding predefined variables, as it can cause the pipeline to behave unexpectedly."

Answer (score 17):

To expand on the GabLeRoux's answer,

I had issues on the pushing stage of the GitLab CI build:

`denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

By changing my `CI_REGISTRY` to `docker.io` (remove the `index.`) I was able to successfully push.

Comment: To state what should be obvious (eventually); the original answer by GabLeRoux has been updated and now "index." prefixes the value in CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE so that it follows the pattern: `index.docker.io/<username>/<project>`